# Work from home (remotely) in the Germany for an Indian company on a visitor visa?

Tags: germany, schengen, indian-citizens, working-holiday-visas

I am planning to visit my friend in Germany and do WFH for my India based company from Germany.
Is this allowed on a visitor visa?